# Is upgrading the piloting subsystem worth it if I always keep it manned?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I always have a crew member at my piloting station. Is it worth it to upgrade the subsystem to increase my evasion?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Upgrading the piloting subsystem won't improve your evasion at all if it's manned. However,

- Subsystem upgrades improve the durability of the subsystem, not just what it does. If you upgrade your piloting subsystem it will be able to take a hit and stay online. (This is also a good reason to upgrade your med-bay and O<sub>2</sub> generator systems, which have otherwise minimal effect on what the room does, and certainly aren't worth the additional power expenditure unless you have a spare zoltan standing around.)
- Don't count on it always being manned. Crew members die. Particularly during the fight with the Rebel Flagship there's a good chance you may have to choose between dying from fire / asphyxiation or leaving the pilot's seat. If you've upgraded your piloting subsystem leaving becomes a more viable option.

Comment: TIL:  asphyxiation; Death due to lack of oxygen